# MySQL has gone away even tho i set the max_allowed_packet to 64 and even 150

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask if somebody had experience such problem in mysql that even tho i set the max_allowed_packet to 64M under the my.cnf and other mysql config it always obstruct the importing of large mysql files.

Here is my my.cnf

```
[mysql]
max_allowed_packet=150M
```

Here is my mysqld.cnf

```
mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 150M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

Hope anyone can help me tune my msql server.

Comment: You sure the value is actually set? `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`

Comment: If mysql wants to complain about a packet too large, it gives you an [error that tells you that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_net_packet_too_large). Did the server crash/restarted? Did it terminate the connection? Check any error message you actually got. Also check the mysql error log, it should contain information if the server crashed or something.